# Should I be using an iOS framework to create a native version of my web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I have a twitter like web application written in Ruby on Rails that allows shops to communicate with their customers.

The web application allows the shop owner to upload product photos as well as new product details.

I want my application to be accessible from an iOS device, and although most of the tasks can be accomplished using my web app with mobile safari, it is impossible to upload images.

What are my options for creating a native ios application? Should I learn objective C, and use Xcode, or are there frameworks out there that make this sort of task easier?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out http://phonegap.com/ or http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/

When you already know webprogramming its much easier to go from that, learning objective-c is a hard road

Comment: I'll give you an upvote, but I disagree that learning objective-c is a hard road.  It isn't prohibitively difficult and the benefits in speed, compatibility and extensibility are most often worth the investment in learning it.

Comment: Well, i think that when you come from webprogramming and know nothing about a compiled language its a hard road in the beginning (and a bit more) - if he want things done fast its mutch easier to save the time :) But of course there are lots of benefits from using the native language. I just know it took me a bit time to get used to it ;-)